# Custom BeforeNavigate-event in WatiN browser

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, watin

I'm trying to change the user agent string using the [WatiN](http://watin.org/) framework by modifying the headers in the "before navigation"-events. I think that I'm really close to a solution, but for some reason I get redirected to a blank page with the code below after the url has been visited for a second or so.

If I comment out the custom BeforeNavigate-events, the browser doesn't redirect to the blank page, which leads me to believe that my custom event needs a slight modification. Do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

To reproduce the issue, download WatiN and run the code below:

```
private SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass _ieInstance;

private const string UserAgent = 
   "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" +
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153" + 
    "Safari/537.36\r\n";

bool _renavigating;
private IE _browser;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ieInstance = _ieInstance = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
    //_ieInstance.BeforeNavigate2 += BeforeNavigate;
    _browser = new IE(_ieInstance);
    _browser.GoTo("http://www.procato.com/my+headers/");
}

void BeforeNavigate(object pDisp, ref object url, ref object flags, 
     ref object targetFrameName, ref object postData, ref object headers, 
     ref bool cancel)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAgent))
    {
        if (!_renavigating)
        {
            headers += string.Format("User-Agent: {0}\r\n", UserAgent);
            _renavigating = true;
            cancel = true;
            _ieInstance.Navigate((string)url, 
                 (string)targetFrameName, (byte[])postData, (string)headers);
        }
        else
        {
            _renavigating = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

@Noseratio's suggestion gives me a blank page as well:

```
readonly SynchronizationContext _sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

void BeforeNavigate(object pDisp, ref object url, ref object flags, 
     ref object targetFrameName, ref object postData, ref object headers, 
     ref bool cancel)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAgent))
    {
        if (!_renavigating)
        {
            var newHeaders = string.Format("User-Agent: {0}\r\n", UserAgent);
            _renavigating = true;
            cancel = true;

            string thatUrl = (string)url;
            object thatFlags = flags;
            object thatTargetFrameName = targetFrameName;
            object thatPostData = postData;
            object thatHeaders = (headers != null && headers != Type.Missing && 
                               headers != System.DBNull.Value) ?
                (headers.ToString() + newHeaders) : newHeaders;

            _sc.Post(_ => 
            { 
                ((SHDocVw.IWebBrowser)pDisp).Navigate(
                    thatUrl, 
                    ref thatFlags,
                    ref thatTargetFrameName,
                    ref thatPostData,
                    ref thatHeaders);
            }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            _renavigating = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to change the useragent on all requests, or is just the direct navigation request to the page enough? Also, do you need to change it multiple times to different things within a single test/process?

Comment: @BenAaronson Sorry, I didn't get this notification for some reason. The request navigating to the page is enough. Yes, each `IE` instance needs to be able to have its own headers.

Answer (score 0):

> The request navigating to the page is enough.

In that case, I'd suggest making your life simpler by ditching the `BeforeNavigate2`, and simply using `_ieInstance.Navigate` to navigate. e.g:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ieInstance = _ieInstance = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
    _browser = new IE(_ieInstance);
    _ieInstance.Navigate("http://www.procato.com/my+headers/", Headers: UserAgent);
}
```

The result shown on procato will be the wrong headers because the loading the page makes additional requests, and those won't have the right headers. However if you use a tool like Fiddler2, you'll see that the initial request has the correct user agent header.